# Find Google Map Line w/ Nokogiri

Tags: nokogiri

Using nokogiri I need to search through some HTML for something like:

```
new GLatLng(-14.468352,132.270434)
```

and then assign the latitude and longitude values in that code to two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us any example HTML. Nokogiri seems to be the wrong tool for this job if you're just searching for plain text. You could simply do:

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739202/find-google-map-line-w-nokogiri').read
match = /new GLatLng\((?<lat>.+?),(?<long>.+?)\)/.match html
p match[:lat].to_f
#=> -14.468352
```

Or, if you need an array of all such matches, say the page also has `new GLatLng(17.3,42.1)` on it:

```
matches = html.scan /new GLatLng\((.+?),(.+?)\)/
p matches
#=> [["-14.468352", "132.270434"],["17.3", "42.1"]]
```

The only reason you might want to use Nokogiri would be to limit your searching to a particular HTML element (e.g. some `<script>` block).